# Google Play is rejecting my app bundle update because targetSdkVersion is 30

Tags: android, google-play-console, targetsdkversion

**Error:**

Your app currently targets API level 30 and must target It least API level 31 to ensure it is built on the latest APIs optimized for security and performance. Change your app's target API level to at least 31)

**Possible Remedy:**

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/11926878?hl=en

> To help ease the transition, we are delaying the enforcement deadline
> for app discoverability from November 1, 2022 to January 31, 2023. You
> can continue to request an extension if you need more time to update
> your app to target API level 31 or above by submitting an extension
> request for your app to continue being discoverable to all Google Play
> users until May 1, 2023. Check your Play Console Inbox Messages for
> links to each of your app’s extension forms.

**Question:**

How to request for extension? I couldn't find the "links to each of your app’s extension forms"

Answer (score 2):

According to the FAQ at the bottom of the page you cited:

> Only apps that are not compliant with the policy will receive an
> extension form via Play Console Inbox message. The message is titled
> "Target API level policy changes will impact the availability of your
> app on Google Play starting Nov 1, 2022."

Other than waiting for Google to send you the info, you could try and update the targetsdkVersion to at least 31.

At the manifest, check that targetapi is at least 31. Check for bugs (if anything has been deprecated), sign and upload.

Edit: App updates are not available for APIs below 31 as of November 2nd 2022.

Comment: My existing app is already on 30 so means it's non compliant already right? For today's submission i can't afford to upgrade to 31 in a short period of time as it will impact a few modules e.g. location service etc...

Comment: @TT_TT: "My existing app is already on 30 so means it's non compliant already right" -- you will not be able to update it until you raise your `targetSdk` to 31. The discoverability change is simply to force you to update your app. "For today's submission i can't afford to upgrade to 31 in a short period of time" -- the requirement to update `targetSdk` to 31 has been published for over a year, and the overall pattern has been in place for a few years.

Comment: According to the google support page, all app updates should be at least 31 (starting November 2nd 2022).

Comment: @AlexT where's the link says "all app updates should be at least 31" I can only find this: "New apps must target Android 12 (API level 31) or higher;" here, new apps is app updates or totally new apps?: https://developer.android.com/google/play/requirements/target-sdk

Comment: @CommonsWare could you give some reference link to this statement please? "the requirement to update targetSdk to 31 has been published for over a year, and the overall pattern has been in place for a few years. "

Comment: @TT_TT: Well, for example, [the Web page that you linked to is updated](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/11926878?hl=en_EN) from time to time. [Here is the April 11 2022 edition](https://web.archive.org/web/20220411105134/https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/11926878) showing the deadline.

Comment: @TT_TT: There's a table, under the "App update requirements". Under "When are app submissions required to target this API level?" it specifies November 1st 2022 for Android API 31. At the same page you pointed out: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/11926878?hl=en
Sorry, I said 2nd November and it's 1st.